# How do you print the value of an int inside square brackets in Java?

Tags: java, syntax

The output of my program needs to be the value of an int printed inside square brackets but i can't work out how to type this so that it will compile!?

Comment: Show the code you have tried...

Comment: Did you try `System.out.println("[" + intValue + "]")` ?

Comment: So i had this System.out.print("[int]")    ..... Added the extra quotes and the plus signs and it now works! Thankyou. Do the plus signs mean anything in particular?

Comment: @BrynDukes Means concatenation in the case of strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am understanding the question.

Say you have an int

```
int number = 0;
```

and you have a print statement.

```
System.out.println("This is the number : [" + number + "]");
```

That is how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

just append the `"[" + number + "]"`

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 10;
        System.out.println("[" + a + "]");
    }
```

**Output**

```
[10]
```

Answer (score 0):

As said:

```
System.out.println("[" + a + "]");
```

The + signs means "and". print string AND int AND string.